# POST request with terminal - jq error: data/0 is not defined at <top-level>

Tags: post, terminal, jq

I am trying to do a POST request through a terminal command:

```
curl --request POST -H 'Content-type: application/vnd.myapp.api+json' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer $77777uTlmlHRfyoUj.$3333DZpH0XB0ER6W3Y.22227WYZZ6xSTQd/J5AvOqA1' \
    -d '{"data":{"id":"mytoken","type":"jwtToken"}}' \
    https://app.com/api/entities/users/apiTokens | \
      jq data.attributes.bearerToken
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0jq:
```

But, I get an error:

```
error: data/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
    data.attributes.bearerToken
    jq: 1 compile error
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are missing `.` before `data`

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a function invocation and there is no such function in jq. If you are trying to access the `"data"` property of an object, you need to use an [Object Identifier-Index filter](https://github.com/api/v3/repos/Myrepo/test/latest). These filters always start with a `.`:

```
jq '.data.attributes.bearerToken'
```

- `jq 'data'` tries to invoke the parameterless function "data"
- `jq '.data'` filters for and returns the value of the "data" property in an object, e.g. `42` for input `{"data": 42}`